# Amazon RDS to Custom MySQL Server InnoDB Key Size

Tags: innodb, mysql, rds

I'd like to export an Amazon MySQL RDS instance to my own server running MySQL. I successfully dumped the database and recreated the users on the new database, but when I go to import the dumpfile, I get:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 25: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Some Googling revealed that InnoDB has a max key size of 767. It turns out that we were using the following options in RDS:

```
innodb_large_prefix=on
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=true
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
```

I added these options to my.cnf, but I got the same error message. I then read that innodb_large_prefix only works on tables with ROW_TYPE=DYNAMIC. It turned out that we were using dynamic rows on RDS, but that these rows were not being created as DYNAMIC in the dumpfile. I then found this StackOverflow post that added the ROW_TYPE=DYNAMIC option to the dumpfile: [Force row_format on mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243973/force-row-format-on-mysqldump)

And yet, still I get the same error message. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is encoding issue.
If latin1 was used on RDS, but UTF-8 in your environment then indexed VARCHAR(256) is the problem.

Because in UTF-8 VARCHAR( 256) becomes VARCHAR( 768 ) internally.

Comment: This was our situation, as well.

Comment: I would suggest either use of `utf8_general_ci` as collation, or migrate to MySQL 5.7, where max key length is 3072 bytes, if `utf8_bin` is essential.